# My vector structure is no iterating as expected

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I get no errors, but my output is not what I wanted. I want to get 'stuff + i' to be the input into a vector. BUT my output is just my initial 'stuff' variable - 1 char.

```
stuff 
tuff 
uff
ff 
f 
/0 
/0
gello?
ello?
llo?
gello?
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Playlist
{
    std::string name;
} ;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Playlist> playlist;

    std::cout << "Input 10 stuff" << std::endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    {
        Playlist ok;
        ok.name = "stuff " + i;
        playlist.push_back( ok ); 
        std::cout << playlist.size() << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<Playlist>::iterator iter = playlist.begin();

    while( iter != playlist.end() )
    {
        std::cout << iter->name << std::endl;
        ++iter;
    }

    std::cout << "gello?" << std::endl;
std::vector::iterator iter = playlist.begin();

while( iter != playlist.end() ) { std::cout << iter->name << std::endl; ++iter; }

std::cout << "gello?" << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this statement

```
ok.name = "stuff " + i;
```

to

```
ok.name = "stuff " + std::to_string( i );
```

As for statement

```
ok.name = "stuff " + i;
```

then in the right side there is used the pointer arithmetic. The string literal is converted to pointer to its first element. So

```
"stuff " + 0 returns pointer to character 's'
"stuff " + 1 returns pointer to character 't'
"stuff " + 1 returns pointer to character 'u'
```

and so on.

So the first push_back deals with string "stuff ". The second - with string "tuff ", the third - with string "uff " and so on.

As result the program has undefined behaviour because sizeof( "stuff " ) is less than 10 and you are trying to access memory beyond the string literal.